# Issue with accessing media folder files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am really facing a strange issue, that is I can not access any file from `media` folder while I can access file from `js` folder which is at the same location like :

`app/public/media`

`app/public/js`

Media folder permission is set to `777` and I don`t have any .htaccess file in the project.

The virtual host config is as below

```
<Directory "/home/ashwani/public_html/www/myproject">
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
#Require all granted
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@gamer.localhost
DocumentRoot "/home/ashwani/public_html/www/myproject/public"
ServerName local.myproject.com

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/css/(.*)$ /css/$1 [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^/js/(.*)$ /js/$1 [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^/img/(.*)$ /img/$1 [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^/fonts/(.*)$ /fonts/$1 [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^/media/(.*)$ /media/$1 [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^/(.*).html$ /$1.html [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^/(.*).css$ /$1.css [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^/(.*?)$ /index.php?_myproject=$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can`t understand what is wrong with this.

Comment: Did you check access / error logs? What does they say?

Comment: yes, I checked logs shows forbidden.

Comment: Can you paste the log entry? Also a ls -l of media folder?

Comment: As a side note, can you explain the *Rewriterule ^/(.*).html$ /$1.html [QSA,L]*? If I follow you correctly you want to serve a real file, so why not just use the *RewriteCond*? *RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f * (only execute the follow up rule if Condition is met, otherwise it will serve the file directly).

Comment: I did this  
#RewriteRule ^/(.*?)$ /index.php?_yamzu=$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteCond %{index.php} !-f
but still not working.

Comment: The order is important, first you need to put the RewriteCond and then the rewrite rule, also notice that the param in the rewrite cond is %{REQUEST_FILENAME} the param %{index.php} won't work.

Comment: I have pasted all configuration above can you please paste all answer so that I can paste it to my config file ? Actually I have no more Idea about configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^/(.*?)$ /index.php?_myproject=$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

I'm not sure if this will work as this is just a simplification of your endless list of rules that IMHO just try to serve real files.